# Shell script does not capture value but Command Prompt can capture and update the data in the variable

Tags: linux, shell, sh, scsi

**Issue**
Why the read_stat is not updated inside the script but works fine from Command Prompt ?

**The actual implementation and output**

**Shell Script :Test1.sh**

sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00 &>read_stat

if grep -w "Good" read_stat; then

```
 printf "PASS"
```

else

printf "FAIL"

**Output while running the script**

$ sudo./Test1.sh

$ sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00

```
cdb to send: 12 00 00 00
```

SCSI Status: Good

FAIL

(base) dd@qqqq: ls -l

-rwxrwxrwx 1 dd   dd         0 Jul 13 11:09 read_stat

**EXECUTE THE COMMAND FROM TERMINAL**

$ sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00 &>read_stat

$ ls -l

-rwxrwxrwx 1 dd   dd        41 Jul 13 11:15 read_stat

$ cat read_stat

SCSI Status: Good

No errors

**Previous Implementation (Ignore)**

**Shell Script: Test1.sh**

1. Created a file as read_stat

-rwxrwxrwx 1 dd   dd         0 Jul 13 10:14 read_stat

2. Executed the below command from Test1.sh

   sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00 &>read_stat
3. ls -l from Command Prompt

   -rwxrwxrwx 1 dd   dd         0 Jul 13 10:18 read_stat

But if the same command "sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00 &>read_stat"

is executed from Command Prompt, then I can see the value inside **read_stat**

*-rwxrwxrwx 1 dd   dd         14 Jul 13 10:18 read_stat*

Why the read_stat is not updated inside the script but works fine from Command Prompt ?

Comment: Is it possible that sg_raw is printing to stderr? Try redirect as 2> file and check the file if it has the output. If this is the case you can redirect stderr to stdout by appending 2>&1 do the command

Comment: @geckos, No error reported and can see the right output on screen (Output is SCSI Status: Good) and this is the data i am trying to direct to a variable. But when trying to divert the stdout to a variable(read_stat), the variable is empty.

Comment: Try passing -o file to sg_raw then read_stat=$(cat file)

Comment: I tried , sg_raw -v -s 1024 -o output1.bin -s 512 -i input.bin /dev/sda SCSI WRITE 16 CMD 


The output1.bin is empty. Shows 0 byte

Dont know if this is the right syntax

Comment: Little things like one character differences can mean a lot here.  Can you post the ouput of your command prompt session where you run the sg_raw command from the prompt, the output of running it from the script, the contents of the script, and an ls -l of the script (to show its attributes).

Comment: @MikeAndrews, i have edited the question. Posted the output from Shell Script and Command Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Used 2>read_stat instead of &>read_stat. Able to capture the data in the variable !

**Old Format :** sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00 &>read_stat

**New Format :** sg_raw -v -s 512 -i ttttt.bin /dev/sg4 12 00 00 00 2>read_stat